# appending 2 dataframes together and increment the ranks while appending

Tags: python, pandas, append, rank

I have 2 dataframes

dataframe1:

```
index cust_id   rank opt
0   customer_1  1   test1
2   customer_1  2   test3 
3   customer_1  3   test4
4   customer_2  1   test1
5   customer_2  2   test4   
7   customer_2  3   test3   
9   customer_3  1   test3   
10  customer_3  2   test4   
11  customer_3  3   test1
```

dataframe2:

```
index cust_id rank opt
1   customer_1  1  new_opt
2   customer_2  2  new_opt
3   customer_3  3  new_opt
```

I want to merge these 2 dataframes together and get the output like this:

```
index cust_id   rank opt
0   customer_1  1   new_opt
1   customer_1  2   test1
2   customer_1  3   test3 
3   customer_1  4   test4
4   customer_2  1   test1
5   customer_2  2   new_opt
6   customer_2  3   test4   
7   customer_2  4   test3   
8   customer_3  1   test3   
9   customer_3  2   test4
10  customer_3  3   new_opt
11  customer_3  4   test1
```

basically I want the rank from dataframe2 remain same and rank in dataframe1 gets incremented for the remaining options after appending the dataframes together.

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a `dense` ranking in both, `concat` the first frame onto the second and then sort. This ensures the row in `df2` appears above the similarly ranked row in `df1`. The new ranking is then a `cumcount` within group

```
df = pd.concat([df2, df1], ignore_index=True).sort_values(['cust_id', 'rank'])
df['rank'] = df.groupby('cust_id').cumcount()+1
```

---

```
       cust_id  rank      opt
0   customer_1     1  new_opt
3   customer_1     2    test1
4   customer_1     3    test3
5   customer_1     4    test4
6   customer_2     1    test1
1   customer_2     2  new_opt
7   customer_2     3    test4
8   customer_2     4    test3
9   customer_3     1    test3
10  customer_3     2    test4
2   customer_3     3  new_opt
11  customer_3     4    test1
```

---

If instead you are generally looking to add `1` to the ranking for all rows with the rank above `new_opt`, regardless of the initial rank, we can do this with a `groupby.apply`. Same first step, but now we use `cummax` to add 1 to all rows within group after `new_opt`. This leads to the same output as above.

```
df = pd.concat([df2, df1], ignore_index=True).sort_values(['cust_id', 'rank'])
df['rank'] = (df['rank'] 
              + (df.opt.eq('new_opt')
                   .groupby(df.cust_id)
                   .apply(lambda x: x.shift().cummax()).fillna(0).astype(int)))
```

Comment: Top one is what I was looking for and it works, thank you!